# Left and right to cancel or confirm slider flutter

Tags: flutter, slider

I need to use a slider which slides both to the left to cancel and right to confirm

[this is the desired slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7ekI.png)

I couldn't find a way to do it, is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using a [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) and customizing it.

```
...

double _currentSliderValue = 5;

Slider customSlider() {
    return Slider(
      value: _currentSliderValue,
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      divisions: 10,
      onChanged: (double value) {
        setState(() {
          _currentSliderValue = value;
        });
        if (_currentSliderValue == 0) // Decline 
        else if (_currentSliderValue == 10) // Accept
        else // Nothing
      },
    );
  }
```

The UI can be achieved by including the `customSlider()` as a child of a `Row` widget as follows (didn't try it but it should be the right path):

```
Row declineOrAcceptSlider() {
    return Row(children: [
      Text("Decline"),
      customSlider(),
      Text("Accept")
    ], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spacedEvenly);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gesture Detector this
Example :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String swipeDirection;

    return GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        swipeDirection = details.delta.dx < 0 ? 'left' : 'right';
      },
      onPanEnd: (details) {
        if (swipeDirection == 'left') {
          //handle swipe left event
        }
        if (swipeDirection == 'right') {
          //handle swipe right event
        }
      },
      child: //child widget
    );
  }
```